# Call methods of childclasses only when child is casted into parent?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have a class train, two child classes intercity and sprinter which are types of trains. Now say I want to print a list of trains. When it is an intercity it shoud print intercity and when it is a sprinter it shoud print sprinter.

I thought this would imply that I create a method print in intercity and in sprinter. However as the program is iterating throug a list with trains java insists on creating a print method in the class train aswell.

So how do I cope with this. I thought of creating the print method which checks whether it is an instance of intercity or sprinter, then casts it into the corresponding type and then calls the print method of that type.

However I want to become a better programmer and it does not look like the best solution to me.

So my question therefore is how should deal with the above described situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a `print` method in the `Train` super-class and override it in the sub-classes. This way you don't have to check the type of a `Train` object before printing it, and no casting is required.

```
public class Train {

    public void print ()
    {
        // here you might have a default printing logic, or you could keep this
        // method abstract and leave the implementation to the sub-classes
    }

}

public class Sprinter extends Train {

    @Override
    public void print ()
    {

    }

}

public class InterCity extends Train {

    @Override
    public void print ()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: It might even be an abstract method, forcing the subclasses to implement it.